# Is Passing a Dynamically Allocated Array to a Function in C an Instance of Pass-by-value or Pass-by-reference?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

To demonstrate, here is an example code recreating the instance of passing a dynamically allocated array to a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void fx1(int* arr) {/* code here */ }
int main() {
    int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    fx1(arr);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

In the example, I first create a dynamically allocated array, **arr**. Then, I pass it to a function called **fx1**.
The title is exactly my question. Is passing a dynamically allocated array to a function in C an instance of pass-by-value or pass-by-reference? I would also like a reference/s (book, documentation, etc) if you have an answer for this.

Comment: `arr` is a pointer. It points to the first element of the array allocated by `malloc`. You pass a pointer to the first element of that array. To call this situation "passing an array" is an abuse of notation.

Comment: C does not have pass by reference.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken note that (1) C does not have pass by reference and that (2) arr is a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, everything is passed by value. In your concrete example `arr` is. You don't have references like in C++ or Java.

Let's take a C++ example:

```
void foo(int& i) {
    ++i;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;

    foo();
}
```

Here, true references are used. `i` is passed by reference and `foo` modifies `i` over a reference to `i`. **No "copying by value" takes place.**

OTOH, in C, you don't have references. You can only write something like

```
void foo(int* i) {
    ++*i;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;

    foo(&i);
}
```

To pass something "by reference"<sup>1</sup> in C, you need to pass a pointer to it, just like you did. The pointer itsself is **passed by value** but it **refers** to a memory area (here `i`) modifiable by both the function **and** the allocator.

In the end, if you want to pass something "by reference" in C, copying by value is always involved. Not so in C++.

Quoting from K&R, 1.8 Arguments - Call by Value:

> In C, all function arguments are passed by value.''

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this is within double quotes. C doesn't have "pass-by-reference." Period.

Comment: "In C, everything is passed by value."
"To pass something "by reference" in C, you need to pass a pointer to it."
The two seem contradictory. Can you explain a little bit more from a C perspective?

Comment: @Mercado To resolve the contradictory part I put double quotes around "by reference." Technically, there is no such thing in C. Anyway, you can pass a pointer to some memory location to a function to let the function modify it.

Comment: Okay. Any basis/source for this information, especially for "In C, everything is passed by value."?

Comment: I don't think I passed a pointer to "it". You can change the contents of the array, but on the contrary, if you change the value of "it" (arr) inside the function call, by giving it a new memory address using malloc, the new memory address will not occur from where you invoked the function call (which is main function) because arr is a local variable in the function. Correct me if I am wrong, I want to understand what it really means to say "pass-by-reference", it seems to be confusing when it comes to arrays.

Comment: @Mercado: For most usages (IIRC all but `&`, `_Alignof`, `sizeof`), an array **decays** to a pointer.

Comment: @Mercado - You also don't pass an array to the function, you pass a pointer (by value). If you want to update the pointer, you pass a pointer to the pointer(!). That's all you have in C. If you want to call that pass-by-reference or not, is up to you.

Comment: I see it that way: References are at a higher abstraction than C provides. So any "reference" is a matter of application semantics, not C.

Comment: I am familiar with the & symbol in the function parameters in C++. Like this: void fnx1(int &a) 
Is this what is considered as pass-by-reference?

Comment: @Mercado Yes, this is a true reference.

Comment: @cad, there's an error in the second code block: `++i` would increment the pointer, not the value. And shouldn't the footnote read "C doesn't have "pass by reference""?

Comment: @alain Two in one... that's fairly bad. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is "both":

The pointer is passed by value, the array "by reference".

[C Standard draft, N1256:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>   ...
>   4 An argument may be an expression of any object type. In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments
>   are evaluated, and each parameter is **assigned the value** of the
>   corresponding argument.
>   ...

I put "both" and "by reference" in quotes, because there are no references in C. A pointer **is not** a reference, but when used to "pass an array" to a function, it is roughly comparable, in the sense that if the function modifies the array, the changes are visible to the caller. I think this helps understanding what happens here.
We say that an array **decays** to a pointer, when passed to a function. "Decay" because the pointer looses some information, namely the length of the array. So saying this is similar to "pass by reference" is meant only from an application point of view.

Comment: Explanation, or source?

Comment: That explains why a pointer is passed by value since the pointer in the function call is another local variable that is different from the one in main. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The pointer in the function is a copy, but it points to the same array.

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason that the array is passed by reference?

Comment: Strictly speaking, everything is passed by value in C. So you pass a pointer by value. But a pointer is a bit like a reference, so you could say you pass an array "by reference". In C, there is no way to pass an array by value, it's impossible.

Comment: C does not have pass by reference, so no, it it not "both". The function gets the **value** of the pointer. Anything else is at a higher abstraction layer beyond the C semantics.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, I know, that's why "both" is in quotes.

Comment: And do not cite long outdated standard drafts. (although I admit **this** has not changes significantly) Here is the final draft for the current standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: Yes, @Olaf, I understand what you mean. But I think viewing a pointer as similar to a reference helps to understand what happens. I updated my answer.

Comment: The question is about C, not higher abstration semantics. And there is a clear difference between pointer an reference: the pointer has a value on its own (the address it points to), the reference's value is the object it points to. As C does not enforce this (like e.g. C++), it is solely a convention beyond the language itself.

Comment: @Olaf, you really don't have to tell me the differences between a reference and a pointer. I wrote *similar*, not *equal*. This is a "beginner" question, so I think it really doesn't help to be too nit-picky. It's about understanding, so higher abstractions are relevant, IMO.

Comment: Especially for a beginner question it **is** relevant to be exact to get the concepts right! Once he has understood, terms can be relaxed a bit. But the latter not on SO, because this will be read by other beginners. So being precise is vital here.

Comment: I withdrew the DV, but you should just might want to add that "reference" is a pure application view and not enforced by the C language/implementation or environment.